# Intra Queue Preemption in yarn Capacity scheduler

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am using hadoop 2.9.2 for intra queue preemption in yarn. My inter queue preemption is working fine and I have set these two parameters shown here: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/data-operating-system/content/properties_for_configuring_intra-queue_preemption.html but still intra queue preemption is not working. Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: How are you testing intra-queue preemption?

Comment: I created a queue and submitted a job with priority 20 in it. Also then I submitted a job with priority 30 in it. I am testing on my local se these two jobs took three containers available in the queue. Then I submitted a job with priority 40 in that  But that job is waiting for one of these two to complete. In my belief it should start immediately by preemption of some containers from the other two preferably 20.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you should use a **lower** number to indicate a higher priority since the 1st priority is always more important than the 20th priority.

This isn't clearly stated but it can be implied by looking at [ResourceManager REST API’s: 
Cluster Reservation API List](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.9.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Reservation_API_List)

> priority
>   int
>   An integer representing the priority of the reservation. A lower number for priority indicates a higher priority reservation. Recurring reservations are always higher priority than non-recurring reservations. Priority for non-recurring reservations are only compared with non-recurring reservations. Likewise with recurring reservations.

And if you dig, you'll find it in the design documents attached to [YARN-4945: [Umbrella] Capacity Scheduler Preemption Within a queue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-4945) which describes this feature.

[image]